# Posting image to a product using the magento REST API 2 gives returns HTTP 500 and error in exception.log

Tags: magento2, api, product-images, rest-api

I am trying to add an image to a product in Magento 2.1 via the REST API using the catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1 service. The request is a POST request to https://example.com/rest/V1/products/$000000000093/media where $000000000093 is the sku of the item I am trying to add the image to. The body of the request is

```
{
  "entry":{
     "types":[
        "image",
        "thumbnail",
        "small_image"
      ],
      "label":"Image",
      "media_type":"image",
      "disabled":false,
      "content":[
        {
          "type":"image\/jpeg",
          "name":"Test123.jpg",
          "base64_encoded_data":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA..."
        }
     ],
   "position":1,
   "file":"\/t\/e\/Test123.jpg"
 }
}
```

This returns a 500 code and checking the Magento exception.log you get the following error:

> main.CRITICAL: exception 'LogicException' with message 'Property "0" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterface".'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you need to define `content` field as object, not array.

*Try to use:*

```
"content": {
    "type":"image\/jpeg",
    "name":"Test123.jpg",
    "base64_encoded_data":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA..."
},
```

*Source*: `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface`

Comment: Ah ha, working now. It's always something simple... thank you, spent way too long on this.